# Cyclist killed in hit-and-run; will cyclists be allowed on the jury?

Tags: voir-dire

In the near future, a motorist who allegedly ran down and killed a cyclist will be going on trial for the offense.

Will the defense be allowed to (a) ask prospective jurors if they are cyclists, and (b) will any potential jurors who answer "yes" be excused from jury service?

Comment: Who are cyclists? People who can ride a bicycle? Who ride every day? Once a week?. Also, how about excluding motorists as well?

Comment: Interesting question. If the answer is "yes", would the prosecution also be allowed to exclude car drivers? And who would be on the jury then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It depends [where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_selection) you are

**Strike for Cause**

In jurisdictions where you can strike for cause the judge would hold a trial to determine if this was a sufficient cause to exclude the juror. The specifics differ by jurisdiction but taking [new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) as a generalization:

> [t]hat the proposed juror does not possess the necessary qualifications or that he has some personal defects which render him incapable of discharging his duty as a juror or that he is not impartial or that he has served on another jury in respect of the same matter or that he has been convicted for an infamous crime.

**Peremptory Challenges**

In many jurisdictions (not [england](/questions/tagged/england)) each side may have the right to a limited number of challanges without cause. For example, in [new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales), that number in criminal trials is 3 (plus 1 if more than 12 jurors will be empaneled - this is often done to provide"spares" in long trials).

**To exclude all cyclists you would have to convince the judge that all cyclists are biased - not an easy task**

Comment: I'll note that they often ask potential jurors questions like "do you or have you worked in [industry related to case]" and even if you answer in the affirmative, you are not automatically excused.

Comment: "the judge would hold a trial to determine if this was a sufficient cause to exclude the juror" Hearing maybe, not trial.

Comment: @Acccumulation the term here is trial (within a trial)